# Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported

Tags: grub2

I have noticed that since some time ago, the following warning message appears when updating grub:

> ```
> Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
> ```

```
cat /etc/default/grub
```

lists the following options:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomdmonddf nomdmonisw fsck.mode=force"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Supposing the following:

- I don't use grub menu.
- I want the boot process not to be slowed down by some grub timeout.

What are the valid options for me?

Removing the line:

> ```
> GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
> ```

or something else?

*OS: Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon 64-bit.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I tried different combinations and the result is, that for the file:

```
/etc/default/grub
```

in my case, when I don't want the grub menu to appear at all, removing the following line, works:

> ```
> GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
> ```

while setting:

> ```
> GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
> ```

Afterwards, don't forget to run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

The warning no longer appears.

Comment: This doesn't work, [details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/762488/how-to-disable-grub-timeout-completely-one-os)

Comment: @АндрейТернити Remove the `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true` line. And try again.