# How to disable grub timeout completely (one OS)?

Tags: ubuntu, grub2

On Ubuntu 23, I want to disable `grub` pause (the default for 30s) completely = I want **0s**. Yes, I am sure. No, I do not have other OSes. I edit file:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Contains

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 #new
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

And update settings

```
sudo update-grub
```

But nothing helps for my Ubuntu 23. I have UEFI and no secure boot. I also try all variants of GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE (menu, countdown, hidden)... How to achieve 0s timeout, please?

**Update.**
I try [@vlastimil-burián](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/762541/481341) without success...
In my Xubuntu 6.2.0-39-generic I have default very long grub timeout...

My default `/etc/default/grub` file is

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUTSTYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Now I try

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

then

```
sudo update-grub
```

After reboot I see default very long delay again... How to disable grub timeout completely?

Answer (score 0):

As per my [other answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400830/126755):

1. remove `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` line
2. keep `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` line
3. run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: It doesn't work... See post above